# Monit with Ansible - invalid mail format '#015'

Tags: linux, debian, ansible, monit

I've been trying to install monit with an ansible playbook. I'm changing the monitrc file and when the playbook restarts monit, I get :

```
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver monit[1857462]: Starting daemon monitor: monit
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver monit[1857465]: /etc/monit/monitrc:10: invalid mail format '#015'
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver monit[1857465]: /etc/monit/monitrc:11: syntax error 'subject: $HOST -- $EVENT $SERVICE#015'
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver monit[1857466]:  failed!
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver systemd[1]: monit.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver systemd[1]: monit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun  8 08:00:30 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon.
```

The conflicting lines in monitrc :

```
set mail-format {
  from: Monit <monit@my-domain.com>
  subject: $HOST -- $EVENT $SERVICE
  message: $EVENT Service $SERVICE
                Date: $DATE
                Action: $ACTION
                Host: $HOST
}
```

Here are the different tests I did :

- Installing monit from playbook ( Installing from apt then copy the monitrc file to its location) : Does not work
- Installing monit manually (installing from apt then copy-pasting the configuration to monitrc) : Works
- Copy-pasting monitrc after the ansible install : Does not work

Monit version is 5.27.2 in both cases and the machine is Debian 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the files I was copying with ansible where in CRLF format. I had to switch them to LF so that monit could read the files.